# React Native (Expo): TouchableOpacity onPress is not a function / is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, touchableopacity, undefined-function

I was following this tutorial on Linkedin-Learning and suddelny my code wouldn't work anymore.
Unfortunately i don't really understand these error messages:

This warning always appears:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onPress` is marked as required in
> `RandomNumber`, but its value is `undefined`.

And if I press one of the "buttons", this error messages comes up:

> TypeError: _this.props.onPress is not a function. (In
> '_this.props.onPress(_this.props.id)', '_this.props.onPress' is
> undefined)

RandomNumber.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class RandomNumber extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    number: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    isDisabled: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  handlePress = () => {
    if (this.props.isDisabled) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onPress(this.props.id);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress}>
        <Text style={[styles.random, this.props.isDisabled && styles.disabled]}>
          {this.props.number}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  random: {
    backgroundColor: "#999",
    width: 120,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    marginVertical: 25,
    fontSize: 35,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  disabled: {
    opacity: 0.2,
  },
});
export default RandomNumber;
```

Game.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import RandomNumber from "./RandomNumber";
import shuffle from "lodash.shuffle";

class Game extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    randomNumberCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    initialSeconds: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onPlayAgain: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  state = { selectedIds: [], remainingSeconds: this.props.initialSeconds };

  gameStatus = "PLAYING";

  randomNumbers = Array.from({ length: this.props.randomNumberCount }).map(
    () => 1 + Math.floor(10 * Math.random())
  );

  target = this.randomNumbers
    .slice(0, this.props.randomNumberCount - 2)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

  shuffledRandomNumbers = shuffle(this.randomNumbers);

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(
        (prevState) => {
          return { remainingSeconds: prevState.remainingSeconds - 1 };
        },
        () => {
          if (this.state.remainingSeconds === 0) {
            clearInterval(this.intervalID);
          }
        }
      );
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  isNumberSelected = (numberIndex) => {
    return this.state.selectedIds.indexOf(numberIndex) >= 0;
  };

  selectNumber = (numberIndex) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      selectedIds: [...prevState.selectedIds, numberIndex],
    }));
  };

  UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (
      nextState.selectedIds !== this.state.selectedIds ||
      nextState.remainingSeconds === 0
    ) {
      this.gameStatus = this.calcGameStatus(nextState);
      if (this.gameStatus !== "PLAYING") {
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
      }
    }
  }

  calcGameStatus = (nextState) => {
    const sumSelected = nextState.selectedIds.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return acc + this.shuffledRandomNumbers[curr];
    }, 0);
    if (this.state.remainingSeconds === 0) {
      return "LOST";
    }
    if (sumSelected < this.target) {
      return "PLAYING";
    }
    if (sumSelected === this.target) {
      return "WON";
    }
    if (sumSelected > this.target) {
      return "LOST";
    }
  };

  render() {
    const gameStatus = this.gameStatus;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[styles.target, styles[`STATUS_${gameStatus}`]]}>
          {this.target}
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.randomContainer}>
          {this.shuffledRandomNumbers.map((randomNumber, index) => (
            <RandomNumber
              key={index}
              id={index}
              number={randomNumber}
              onPress={this.state.selectNumber}
              isDisabled={
                this.isNumberSelected(index) || gameStatus !== "PLAYING"
              }
            />
          ))}
        </View>
        {this.gameStatus !== "PLAYING" && (
          <Button title="Play Again" onPress={this.props.onPlayAgain} />
        )}
        <Text>{this.state.remainingSeconds}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
    flex: 1,
  },
  target: {
    fontSize: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#bbb",
    margin: 50,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  randomContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
  },

  STATUS_PLAYING: {
    backgroundColor: "#bbb",
  },
  STATUS_WON: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },
  STATUS_LOST: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
});

export default Game;
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Game from "./Game";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { gameId: 1 };
  resetGame = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { gameId: prevState.gameId + 1 };
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Game
        key={this.state.gameId}
        onPlayAgain={this.resetGame}
        randomNumberCount={6}
        initialSeconds={10}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've already tried some solutions from other posts, but none of them worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are passing `this.state.selectNumber` as `onPress` to `RandomNumber`, which doesn't exist. I think it is supposed to be `this.selectNumber` instead.

Comment: omg, thank you so much. Why didn't I see this. :D